# Using backspace to move to previous folder

Tags: c#, telerik

How do i move to previous node in a radtreeview. i am using telerik.
here is my Load witch display the radtreeview:

```
public void LoadDataMyComputer()
{
    try
    {
        RadTreeNode rootNode = radTreeView1.Nodes.Add("C:\\work_Bogdan");
        rootNode.Tag = "C:\\work_Bogdan";
        Stopwatch watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        LoadFoldersTree(rootNode);


        watch.Stop();
        ParamLoadingTime = (watch.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000.0);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

here is my pressKey event where i have to write the code to move to previous folders:

```
private void radTreeView1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Back)
    {
        // here have to be the code to move to prev. folder
        MessageBox.Show("asd");
    }
}
```

any answer is helpful. thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

I created a list of nodes.

then when i press the backspace key it loads my form with the previous node(m_History[m_History.Count - 1] is the previous node)

and the code looks like this:

```
private void radTreeView1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        //if backspace is pressed go to previous node
        if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Back)
        {
            if (m_History.Count == 0)
                return;

            RadTreeNode nNode = m_History[m_History.Count - 1];
            //Load with the m_History[m_History.Count - 1] node from the list(m_History)
            LoadTree(nNode);

            //remove the last node
            m_History.Remove(nNode);
        }
    }
```